# unable to fetch GET form data in url in django view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

i am trying to make a search view, and the results are shown. so for without pagination the search view works fine but when i added pagination it stopped working. Below is my code

views.py

```
def search_query(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        #try:
        if 'q' in request.GET:
            query_string= request.GET.get('q')

            if len(query_string) == 0:
                return HttpResponseBadRequest('Invalid Search')
            else:
                query_list = query_string.split(' ')
                posts = _search(query_list)
                paginator = Paginator(posts, 1) 
                page = request.GET.get('page')
                if page is None:
                    page = 1
                else:
                    pass
                try:
                    posts = paginator.page(page)

                except PageNotAnInteger:

                    posts = paginator.page(1)
                    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
                except EmptyPage:

                    posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

                    return HttpResponseBadRequest()

                context = {
                    'posts': posts,
                }
                return render(request, 'search/search.html', {'posts': posts,})
    #except:
        #   return HttpResponseBadRequest('Outside Try')
```

Function below does the actual searching

```
def _search(query_list):
    result = []
    for query in query_list:
        query = query.lower()
    try:        
        posts = Post.objects.order_by('-date_created').filter(tag__tag__icontains=query)
        for post in posts:
            if post in result:
                pass
            else:
                result.append(post)
    except:
        result = None
    return result
```

below is the snippet of search.html pagination part

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">

        {% if posts.has_previous %}
            {% comment %} <a href="?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}">previous</a> {% endcomment %}
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?q={{ request.GET.q }}&?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="page-item disabled">
                <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}

          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?q={{ request.GET.q }}&?page={{ posts.number }}">{{ posts.number }}</a></li>

        {% if posts.has_next %}
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?q={{ request.GET.q }}&?page={{ posts.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

now the problem is the value of page here is None when i print(page)

```
page = request.GET.get('page')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> no need to add `?` before `page` when page is second argument

change the code with this one

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">

        {% if posts.has_previous %}
            {% comment %} <a href="?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}">previous</a> {% endcomment %}
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?q={{ request.GET.q }}&page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="page-item disabled">
                <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}

          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?q={{ request.GET.q }}&page={{ posts.number }}">{{ posts.number }}</a></li>

        {% if posts.has_next %}
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?q={{ request.GET.q }}&page={{ posts.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you do like this

```
def search_query(request):
   query_params = request.query_params.dict()
```

from **query_params** contains what you passed url